# How to select a date range in a pandas group by?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe in the format below, which I want to group by Date and Item, and then get a count of the serial numbers for each item every day.

However, I want to limit the date in the dataframe to a date range from the most recent to 10 days ago, and exclude any data outside this range.

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date' : ['2018-01-01', '2018-01-01', '2018-01-02', '2018-01-03','2018-01-03', '2018-01-03', '2018-01-06, '2018-01-10'], 'Item' : ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana', 'Potato','Kiwi', 'Banana', 'Kiwi', 'Apple'],'serial no':['124161', '7124112', '123237', '765432','823542', '263872', '873492', '2342784']})
df
```

In order to get the dataframe to the format I want I do the below and get a df such as:

```
df = df.dropna(subset = ['Date','serial no']).sort_values(by = ['Date','serial no']).groupby(['Date','serial no']).count()
df
```

How can I limit the date range of my data in the way I want?

I tried using something like `datetime.datetime.now() -datetime.timedelta(10)` but this gave me type errors.

Comment: Typo in your initialization: `2018-01-06` is missing a quotation mark to close the string.

Comment: Additionally, `serial no': ['Item' : ` is incorrect. Take a moment and retest your code, then update.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, no clue how to write Markdown so made these silly mistake, can I ask how I can add a code block to display my dataframes?

Comment: Best the way you did it above. A solution would be to paste the output of `df.to_records()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must first convert the date column to datetime data type:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
```

Now you can select the required range:

```
slice = df[df.Date >= df.Date.max() - datetime.timedelta(10)]
```

P.S. The filtering should be done *before* grouping. Incidentally, it will make grouping faster.

Comment: Thanks, but when I try this, i get `Dataframe has no attribute: 'Date'` . This is presumably as the groupby turns Date into the index, any way around this?

Comment: Filter your data before you perform your groupby.

Answer (score 1):

If you want your base date to be derived from the max date in the frame then use DYZ reply. If you're looking to base it on current date like your approach you can use the following.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
days_to_subtract = 10
minDate_str = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=days_to_subtract)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

df_raw = pd.DataFrame(
{'Date' : ['2019-05-10', '2019-05-20', '2019-08-02', '2019-01-03','2019-08-03', '2019-01-03', '2018-01-06', '2018-01-10'], 
 'Item' : ['Apple', 'Pear', 'Banana', 'Potato','Kiwi', 'Banana', 'Kiwi', 'Apple'],
 'serial no':  ['124161', '7124112', '123237', '765432','823542', '263872', '873492', '2342784']})

df = df_raw[df_raw['Date']>=minDate_str]


df = df.dropna(subset = ['Date','serial no']).sort_values(by = ['Date','serial no']).groupby(['Date','serial no']).count()
df
```

Answer (score 0):

**Select by Date Diff:**

```py
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

# Choose some date, could be today
today = pd.to_datetime('today')
df['Days_Since'] = (today-df['Date']).dt.days

# Choose some choice of time, here in days
df_slice = df[df['Days_Since']<=516]

print(df_slice)
#   Date    Item    serial no   Days_Since
# 6 2018-01-06  Kiwi    873492  516
# 7 2018-01-10  Apple   2342784 512
```

To keep [DYZ's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4492932/dyz) approach, you could compare dates with `df.Date.max()`

**Thereafter, you could aggregate by groups.**

```py
df_counts = df_slice.groupby(['Date','serial no'])[['Item']].count()

print(df_counts)
#       Item
# Date  serial no   
# 2018-01-06    873492  1
# 2018-01-10    2342784 1
```